# How to size two textview side by side and use 50% width of screen

Tags: java, android, textview

I have the following code which has 2 textviews side by side in 4 rows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="4" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCodeNameDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="cnsdsdsf:"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff0000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCodeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#00FF00" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVersionDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="vnddf: "
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#00ff00" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVersion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff0000" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReleaseDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="rdsdfsdfsfsdf: "
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#FF0000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRelease"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#00FF00" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAPIDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="apdd: "
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#00ff00" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAPI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff0000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It displays the following:

[image]

How do I modify the code to make it ALWAYS 50%/50% no what text is inside the textview?

Comment: Oh, my eyes. That "Action Bar" is all wrong.

Comment: I customized it. So it's not the default "Action Bar".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change the `width` of your `TextView`s both to `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCodeNameDetail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"              <!-- here -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cnsdsdsf:"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ff0000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCodeName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"              <!-- and here -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#00FF00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When using `weight` in a `horizontal` `LinearLayout` you need to have a `width` of `0dp`. Likewise, in a `vertical` `LinearLayout`, you would want a `height` of `0dp`.

Comment: @MikeM. I haven't tried it but I wouldn't think so. That wouldn't leave room for the second `TextView` (I don't think). Last time I read the docs for it, `0dp` should be used when using `weight` on a `View`.

Comment: @MikeM. I will test and let you know :)

Comment: @MikeM. ok, thanks for the update. I would stick with `0dp` since that is what the Google devs sugges (AFAIK anyway) unless there is a reason you *need* `match_parent`. I wonder if it makes a difference what the `width` of the `parent` is. I could see it working if it is `wrap_content`...

Comment: @MikeM. of course, I don't pretend to know everything Android so hearing other ideas and suggestions are always welcome

Comment: @codeMagic shouldnot the android:layout_weight="1" of linear layout be 2 and the textview doesnot maintain its position when the text doesnot fit in single line

Comment: Use match_parent if the other sibling will be dynamically added or removed. You also have to use match_parent if any sibling is using match_parent. Otherwise stick to 0dp; the OS likes it best.

Answer (score 1):

The code worked for me, but I substracted both of "0dp" arguments and instead used only "weight=1". I am using a custom row maker for a list view and it worked :D